# Maven Building failure Spring boot app on amazon linux

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, spring-boot

I execute maven clean package and appear the following message.I am trying to install it on Amazon ec2 instance. When I execute java -version shows:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Enviroment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12,mixed mode)
```

But when I write javac -version shows:

```
javac 1.7.0_191
```

And the Message is:

```
[Error][1]
```

The pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>travelg</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>travelg</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
     8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have a JRE 8 but only a JDK 7 installed.

Comment: Can you please edit you post and add the output as text in your post...and don't use image links...

Comment: What is the full error message? `[Error][1]` is truncated.